# Cache result of function

Tags: javascript, node.js

How I can store result of an async function in variable in node? For example I want to parse a website and get some info, but I don't want to constantly request data, I want to get all page only once. Here is code:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');

function SiteParser() {
  const SITE = 'http://www.anywebsite.com';

  // variable for caching html
  var $ = getBody();

  function getBody(SITE){
    // request html
    request(SITE, function(error, response, html) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        return cheerio.load(html);
      }
      else {
        throw new Error('Could not parse web site\nError text: ' + error);
      }
    })
  }

  //declaration of class methods using cached html
  this.getCategories = function() {};
  this.getNews = function() {};
}
```

How can I be sure, that response will be received, when I will call methods of the class?
Or is this a bad practice?

Comment: Please include the code of the async call.

Comment: Also are you familiar with callbacks ?

Comment: @trincot async call is just simple http request using request.js, is it really necessary here?

Comment: @Rabee I know about them, but I don't know how to use them in this case

Comment: are you new to programing in general or just to JS?

Comment: As your question is about storing the result of an async call: yes, please provide the code. it is at the core of your question.

Comment: @trincot ok, I have added code

Comment: @David Haim new in general

Comment: What is `cheerio` though? Without understanding your problem fully, this screams `Promise`

Comment: @JSelser cheerio is a lib in npm. Added dependencies in code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `var $ = getBody();` does not work as you want it, since `getBody` does not return anything. It is the inner callback that returns something, but that return value is for ever lost. Moreover, that callback is called asynchronously, so you could not get it via `var $ = getBody();`, since `getBody` finishes before the callback is executed.

So, here is a quick way to resolve that issue. The constructor takes an optional callback function as argument:

```
function SiteParser(onready) {
  const SITE = 'http://www.anywebsite.com';

  // variable for caching html
  var $;
  var that = this; // maintain reference to this instance of SiteParser

  function getBody(SITE){
    // request html
    request(SITE, function(error, response, html) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        $ = cheerio.load(html); // store the result
        that.ready() // notify client that html has been retrieved
      }
      else {
        throw new Error('Could not parse web site\nError text: ' + error);
      }
    })
  }

  //declaration of class methods using cached html
  this.getCategories = function() {
      if ($ === undefined) throw new Error('Not ready yet');
      // extract categories from $ and return them
  };
  this.getNews = function() {
      if ($ === undefined) throw new Error('Not ready yet');
      // extract news from $ and return it
  };
  this.ready = onready || function() {}; // callback for being notified
}
```

Now you can write:

```
parser = new SiteParser;
parser.ready = function () {
    var cats = parser.getCategories();
    // ...etc
};
```

or also:

```
parser = new SiteParser(function () {
    var cats = parser.getCategories();
    // ...etc
});
```

#### Promise

The above code exposes the *getCategories* and *getNews* methods even when the HTML has not yet been retrieved. This is not so nice.

Using the promise concept you can improve on this by only providing the SiteParser instance when all is ready. Here is some (untested) code you could use with [promise for nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise):

```
var Promise = require('promise');

// SiteParser now needs to be given the HTML in the constructor:
function SiteParser(html) {
    var $ = $cheerio.load(html)

    //declaration of class methods using cached html
    this.getCategories = function() {
        // extract categories from $ and return them
    };
    this.getNews = function() {
        // extract news from $ and return it
    };
}

// a separate Promise object takes care of the retrieval:
function promiseSiteParser() {
  const SITE = 'http://www.anywebsite.com';

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // request html
    request(SITE, function(error, response, html) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        resolve(new SiteParser(html));
      }
      else {
        reject(error);
      }
    })
  });
}

promiseSiteParser().then(function (parser) {
    var cats = parser.getCategories();
    // ...etc
}, function (error) {
    throw new Error('Could not parse web site\nError text: ' + error);
});
```